# IIS UrlRewrite for subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to simply do a subdomain rewrite to a directory.  Example, http*://member.mydomain.com would redirect to http*://mydomain.com/memberarea/.  I don't want ALL subdomains to do this, just the defined "member" one.

Here is the code I have, and it does not work.  I'm obviously missing something...

```
<rule name="Member Pages" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.+)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)://member\.example\.com($)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://example.com/MemberArea/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

My hope is this would also make http://member.example.com/Report/SomeReport.aspx resolve to http://example.com/MemberArea/Report/SomeReport.aspx.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @LexLi - Thanks for the response. but in no way does that answer my question.  It shows how to rewrite a single page to another page.  I'm looking to rewrite a subdomain to another path than the root directory.

Comment: Read carefully to see how `HTTP_HOST` matching works. Your condition above is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule will be redirected to the http*://member.mydomain.com http*://mydomain.com/memberarea/

```
   <rule name="test2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^member\.(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/memberarea" />
    </rule>
```